# proof by induction : graph does not contain Kr+1 as a subgraph, has no more than ? edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

So I have to prove by induction in the number of the vertices of the graph this sentence:

### Let r$\ge$ 2.

### i)Use (strong) induction in the number of vertices to prove that, for n$\ge1$ every ( simple non- directed) graph that does not contain K$_{r+1}$ ( complete graph with (r+1) #vertices) , has no more than

### $(r-1)n^2 /2r$ edges.

### ii) Prove that there exists a graph , with kr vertices , that does not contain  K$_{r+1}$, as a subgraph.

Okay so the idea is this:

1. **Base** If n = 1 , then the graph obviously does not contain Kr+1 as a subgraph and it is easy to show that the formula is true  if n
   =2 the same
2. **Induction hypothesis**

   Suppose it is true for every graph with n = k $\le$ r
3. **Induction Step**

   we will prove that it is true for a graph with n = k + 1 , vertices

   **Proof)** We can , make two different vertices teams , one with (n -r) vertices and another one with r vertices. Since $(n -r) = k + 1 -r < r$ and $r $\le$ r$ , in both teams we can use the induction hypothesis , and find the maximum number of edges between their
   vertices.For the team with (n-r) it is no more than : $(n-r)^2(r-1)/2r$ edges and for the team with r vertices it is no more than $r^2(r-1)/2r$ edges. My problem , is when I think about the edges among
   vertices of the two teams . How I make sure , that these edges do
   not create Kr+1?
   Since I supposed in the Induction Hypothesis , that k$\le$r $=>$ k+1$\le$

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see [here](/help/notation). Could you format your question, it's a bit difficult to read.
Thanks

Comment: when you say a bit difficut to read.. you mean ? Is it my grammar or the format?

Comment: @brucebanner, you're off to a good start with the TeX formatting edits. Using "\ge" and "\le" instead of ">=" and "<=" will make things look even better, as will "K_{r+1}" instead of "Kr+1". Also, you really don't need the asterisk to indicate multiplication.

Comment: You assume that your graph $G$ satisfies all conditions, in particular, it does not contain a $K_{r+1}$ by assumption. Now you want to show that the edges in $n-r$-vertex graph plus the edges in $r$-vertex graph plus the edges inbetween add up to at most the number in the claim. Here you need to use that the whole setting contains no $K_{r+1}$, otherwise the numbers that come up are too big.

Comment: Plus, your hypothesis must read "for all $n\le k$" instead of "$n=k\le r$". You don't know any upper bound on the vertex number, so you need to show it for all vertex numbers.